# Display WooCommerce store notice / demo store on specific product/category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to display the WooCommerce store notice, not site wide, but only on the specific categories or products. I would like to display it on `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` and `woocommerce_before_single_product`. Like in these visual guides:

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

How can I achieve this? I thought I could print the WooCommerce store notice with `woocommerce_demo_store` but it did not work. Thank you.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );`

It doesn't show anything

`woocommerce_demo_store` is a woocommerce hook http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_demo_store/

Comment: Where is your `woocommerce_demo_store` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we will remove the action that displays the default store notice:

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
```

We will add back the store notice at our required location on the selected pages:

```
if ( is_product_category( array( 'clothing', 'decor' ) ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
}
```

Change `'clothing', 'decor'` with your product category's slug.

```
if ( is_single( array( 159, 160 ) ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
}
```

Change `'159', '160'` with your product's ID.

*Note: You can use name, slug or ID in the input array for both `is_product_category()` and `is_single()` functions.*

---

Here is the complete code to put into your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function lh_conditional_store_notice() {

    // Remove default 'woocommerce_demo_store' notice
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );

    // Add back the woocommerce_demo_store' notice, but on the selected pages
    // Show notice on the 'clothing' and 'decor' categories at 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop'
    if ( is_product_category( array( 'clothing', 'decor' ) ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
    }

    // Show notice on single products having ID '159' and '160' at 'woocommerce_before_single_product'
    if ( is_single( array( 159, 160 ) ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_demo_store' );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'lh_conditional_store_notice' );
```

Tested and working on:

- WordPress 5.0.3
- Twentyninteen 1.2
- WooCommerce 3.5.4
- Localhost (XAMPP for Windows 5.6.15)

Comment: Hi
Would it be possible to display the notice as a cookie pop. That is to say, that it is displayed once and disappears unless you clear the cookies?